# Android app closing automatically on using volley in marshmallow os

Tags: android, android-volley, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using volley in android for handling web service. My app is getting closed automatically without any error or crash report in logcat but is running proper in device with android version less then Kitkat. I am using lenovo k3 note running android version 6.0 (Marshmallow) and volley version 1.0.0. Can someone help me with this issue or can suggest some another better library for handling web services. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: atleast provide code or logcat trace, remember logcat trace of crash period

Comment: I think that issue is not related to volley, just do one thing change the targetSdkVersion to 19 in your build.gradle under defaultConfig tag and check in same device.

Comment: I am not getting what code to be shared. Because the app is getting close at any point of time and in any screen and even dosent show any error like stuff in logcat.

Comment: Done downgrading the targetSdkVersion to 19. Dosen't helped :(